# SharePoint 2016 LDAP Filter

Tags: profile-sync, 2016, ldap

With Edit Connection Filters gone in SharePoint 2016, I'm trying to create a LDAP filter to keep any AD imported accounts, without any data in their "Title" field, out of SharePoint.

Does anyone know how to make this work? I'm a total LDAP noob.

Comment: I am trying to put an LDAP filter in 2016 for AD import In 2013 the filer is: extensionAttribute13 Equals 1 I can’t seem to find the equivalent LDAP equivalent for 2016: Any ideas?

Comment: Hi @ Jim Ehrenberg and welcome to SharePoint.StackExchange . You have posted a new question in the answer field, and I would advise you to ask a new question instead. Use the "Ask Question" button in the upper right corner. You can always find out more in the [Help Section](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/help/asking)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe this is the query you're looking for:

```
(&(title=*)(objectClass=user))
```

Comment: No luck, I'm still getting all the untitled accounts.

Comment: Fixed the query, misread the question.

Comment: Yep, after reading your original I thought "Hmm maybe the opposite?". Works great, thanks very much for the help!