# Filters in user profile sync service

Tags: 2016

I need to exclude the disabled users in AD but I can't edit connection filter in user profile service in SP 2016

How can add exclution filter  in SharePoint 2016 with SharePoint AD import option

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't edit the `connection filters` with `SharePoint Active Directory import`, it's only available with `External Identity Manager`.

As **@4rchit3ct♦** said, you should use the `Filter in LDAP syntax for Active Directory Import` instead of editing the `connection filters`. in case, you enabled `SharePoint Active Directory import`.

---

**But in your case**, you can only check **Filter out disabled users** to exclude the disabled users!

**Steps**

- Central Admin > manage Service Application.
- Manage USer Profile > Configure Synchronization Connections
- Edit your connection, just check `Filter out disabled users`

[image]

---

**In case,  you need to use Use LDAP Filter**

- Add the below LDAP filter syntax to exclude the disabled users

  ```
  (!(UserAccountControl:1.2.840.113556.1.4.803:=2))
  ```

Answer (score 1):

Use LDAP filter.

> The AD import option does not provide object filtering based on object
>   property values (you must use simple LDAP filters).

Reference: [Configure profile synchronization by using SharePoint Active Directory Import in SharePoint Server](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/administration/configure-profile-synchronization-by-using-sharepoint-active-directory-import)

See: [SharePoint 2016 LDAP Filter](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/a/193858/6382)